# Can't migrate existing MySQL Wordpress database to Docker with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to migrate a pre-existing Wordpress install from an exported SQL file to a local Docker development environment. I'm somewhat new to Docker, but I have gone through some tutorials and documentation. The problem appears to be that the "wordpress" and "phpmyadmin" services cannot access the database.

I did a search & replace in Vim on the SQL file to replace instances of the original URL with "http://localhost:8000". Then I used docker-compose.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    volumes:
      - ./dbdata-import/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ # Where my exported SQL file is stored
      # I also tried -./dbdata-import/thedata.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/thedata.sql
      - ./dbdata:/var/lib/mysql # So local database changes persist
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wp_database
      MYSQL_USER: wp_username
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wp_password

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:php7.3-apache
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wp_username
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wp_password
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wp_database
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: wp_ #Tried without and without this
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - ./wp-vol:/var/www/html

  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.9.4
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      PMA_USER: admin
      PMA_PASSWORD: phpmyadmin_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

It might be worth noting that I use [this fix](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/418) so I can still use OpenVPN. Basically, I created a subnet by running *docker network create localdev --subnet 10.0.1.0/24*. I also added this file next to my docker-compose.yml:

```
# docker-compose.override.yml
version: '3.7'
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: localdev
```

When I access *http://localhost:8000*, I don't get anything and the browser times out. When I access *http://localhost:8080* for PHPMyAdmin, I get the error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
Cannot connect: invalid settings.
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'admin'@'10.0.1.3' (using password: YES)
phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

It seems odd this would be a credential issue. I pulled the Wordpress database information straight from wp-config.php on the host server. I also tested the database, username and password by signing into the MySQL CLI on the host server.

I used *docker-compose down -v* to delete volumes after I finished and *docker volumes ls* appears to be empty. So I don't think this is an issue with */docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* not running because MySQL already initalized. However, I'm not sure.

I've been troubleshooting this for awhile now. I've done an almost identical Docker setup without */docker-entrypoint-initdb.d* to create fresh Wordpress installs. That works fine. I could really use some help. I'm currently running Debian 10. Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I'm still having issues. I verified that I still have the same issues when I shutdown OpenVPN, remove docker-compose.override.yml and remove the localdev network. I get all the same problems. The only difference is that PHPMyAdmin gives me a different IP address after "admin@", which is expected.

I logged into my MySQL container using *docker exec -it*. Running MySQL CLI with my username and password worked. The tables looked like all the data was imported by docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. **So the issue doesn't appear to be with docker-entrypoint-initdb.d, but rather the wordpress and phpmyadmin services can't access the database.**

**UPDATE 2: I fixed MyPHPAdmin.** I didn't realize that PMA_USER and PMA_PASSWORD need to match the Wordpress database. I also needed PMA_HOST to include the port number:

```
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:4.9.4
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db:3306
      PMA_USER: wp_username
      PMA_PASSWORD: wp_password
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

I still need help with Wordpress.

Comment: Are you using same credentials that you used to have in your original db - from which you are migrating? Or are you trying to set new credentials via MYSQL_USER and similar variables?

Comment: @taleodor MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD is a new password. I don't think I have the MySQL root password from the production host server. My understanding of the MySQL docker image is that doesn't matter because it creates a new root account on container initialization. The rest of the environmental variables match what is in the original db from which I'm migrating.

Comment: So assuming you're not using root password, it's fine. What I can suggest to debug - 1. docker exec into your mysql container and check if you can connect to db using credentials for wordpress / phpmyadmin, 2. docker exec into wordpress container, manually install mysql client and see if you can connect to db container from there. Observe possible errors for clues and play with credentials if an issue is there.

Comment: I know how to do this, do you still need help?